# ionic 2 inappbrowser header overlap

Tags: cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

i have this code

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser(URL,'_blank','location=no,hardwareback=yes');
```

After exitting this browser im getting the header under the status bar in IOS

I tried this approach but its not working with all pages:

```
let self=this;
  browser.on('exit').subscribe(function(event) {
    if (self.platform.is('ios')) {
    var IOSHeader = document.getElementById('HeaderMarginTop');
    self.renderer.setElementStyle(IOSHeader, 'top', '20px');
  }
  });
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: After updating its automatically fixed.